# Vector parallel to the line

Tags: vectors

English isn't my native language.

I'm learning vector, and i'm having a question.

I know that term 'parallel' is used to show relationship between (two lines) or (two vectors) or (two planes) or (one line and one plane).

Yes, many math books 'define' 'parallel' in these case.

But many math books don't 'define' what is parallel between (one vector and one line).

And they used term 'parallel' between (one vector and one line).

What exactly 'parallel' means between one vector and one line??

Comment: I'd imagine if the line's direction vector is a scalar multiple of the given vector.  Never came across that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reasonable definition:

A line $\mathbf r=\mathbf p+\lambda\mathbf u$ and a vector $\mathbf v$ are **parallel** to each other (alternatively: **collinear**) if there exists some real $k$ such that $\mathbf v=k\mathbf u.$

(In particular, the zero vector is parallel to every line.)

Comment: That's a good definition of parallelism, but **not** [collinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity).

Comment: @RobArthan If you mean that collinearity does not typically apply to vectors, I like to say "collinear vectors" ([definition 2 on page 2](https://academic.macewan.ca/burok/Math120/notes/n_intro.pdf)) over "parallel vectors" because  a) the former emphasises the fact that vectors are "portable" by translation in space;  b) some texts distinguish between vectors being "parallel" and "antiparallel", so saying "collinear" sidesteps this potential ambiguity.